# JavaConfig "auto" injection of beans

Tags: spring, inject, spring-java-config

I had being using the JSR 330 @Inject annotation to autowire my Spring beans. I started experimenting by removing the @Inject annotation - yet my application context still gets loaded correctly. Not sure if this is expected and cant find any spring documentation to verify this use case.

```
// This context is loaded correctly - and beans exist for B, C and Db
final ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
```

---

```
@Import({ B.class })
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

@Bean
public Db db() {
   return new Database();
}

@Bean
// I thought this method would need an @Autowire or @Inject annotation to resolve b!?
public C c(final B b){
  return new C(b);
}
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
 public class BConfig {

 @Bean
 public B b() {
    return new B();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Autowired` (or `@Inject` if you prefer) is implicit in `@Bean` methods (always has been as far as I know).

Comment: makes sense - and ties in with what I'm seeing. Would really like to see some docs that call this out though.. Configuration or Bean dont  mention this behaviour at all.

Comment: I don't think it's really considered best practice (makes the code a bit brittle). But I have seen enough examples to know it's common. You can always raise documentation pull requests in Spring.